# Finding Web.API URL from a website

Tags: c#, .net, rest, asp.net-web-api, fiddler

I have a website which calls web API https://www.dreamtrips.com/

How can I find the web APIs used by this website to call different data?

Will fiddler give you the list of web API URLs called by this website?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use network tab in developer tools (F12) in browser to monitor all network calls. However, if the site does not have a public web API, the methods that are called will most likely be protected by CORS policy.

Comment: Thanks, in which tab we can see the API URL on the network tab if the API is public? I can see multiple column names like name, URL so on...

Comment: You can click on concrete action then in request properties there is action URL.